# How to double check inside if without writing the same thing twice?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

Is there a way in `javascript` (or typescript) to avoid re-writing the same object twice inside an `if` statement condition?

Something like this:

```js
if (A != null || A != B) {
 // do something here
}

// something in the form of this:
if (A != null || != B) { // avoid re-writing "A" here
// do something here
}
```

Anyone has any suggesgtion or even other questions related to this one?

Comment: How can `A` equal `B` if it is null?

Comment: This is simple and redable. Keep it as it is

Comment: @mousetail if `B` is null.

Comment: @mousetail so in my case `A` is a number, `A` can possibly be `null` or can have a `number` value. Basically i want to do something when  `A` is `NOT NULL` or if `A` has a value when is not equal to 0

Comment: Anyway i think you guys are right i should keep it as it is. Sometimes i'm overthinking the task and end up creating problems even where is not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: *Basically i want to do something when A is NOT NULL or if A has a value when is not equal to 0* if you want to check for a valid number which is not exactly zero you could just use `if(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do :

```
if([B, null].includes(A)) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in shortcut in `if` conditions. If in reality `A` is a cumbersome expression that you want to avoid rewriting, the usual solution would be a temporary variable:

```
if ( (t=A) != null || t != B ) {
```